# Ошибка "Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name"?

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться, консоль выдает ошибку "Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name" ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   try {
 $('#effect-canvas').ripples({
   resolution: 350,
   perturbance: 0.01
 });
   } catch (e) {
 $('.error').show().text(e);
   }
 });

 function($) {

   var gl;
   var $window = $(window); // There is only one window, so why not cache the jQuery-wrapped window?

   String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
 return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
   }; // Stupid Chrome

   function hasWebGLSupport() {
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
 var result = context && context.getExtension('OES_texture_float') && context.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear');
 canvas.remove();
 return result;
   }

   var supportsWebGL = hasWebGLSupport();

   function createProgram(vertexSource, fragmentSource, uniformValues) {
 function compileSource(type, source) {
   var shader = gl.createShader(type);
   gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
   gl.compileShader(shader);
   if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
     throw new Error('compile error: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
   }
   return shader;
 }

 var program = {};

 program.id = gl.createProgram();
 gl.attachShader(program.id, compileSource(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource));
 gl.attachShader(program.id, compileSource(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource));
 gl.linkProgram(program.id);
 if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program.id, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
   throw new Error('link error: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program.id));
 }

 // Fetch the uniform and attribute locations
 program.uniforms = {};
 program.locations = {};
 gl.useProgram(program.id);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
 var name, type, regex = /uniform (\w+) (\w+)/g,
   shaderCode = vertexSource + fragmentSource;
 while ((match = regex.exec(shaderCode)) != null) {
   name = match[2];
   program.locations[name] = gl.getUniformLocation(program.id, name);
 }

 return program;
   }

   function bindTexture(texture, unit) {
 gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + (unit || 0));
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   }

   // RIPPLES CLASS DEFINITION
   // =========================

   var Ripples = function(el, options) {
 var that = this;

 this.$el = $(el);
 this.$el.addClass('ripples');

 // If this element doesn't have a background image, don't apply this effect to it
 var backgroundUrl = (/url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/.exec(this.$el.css('background-image')));
 if (backgroundUrl == null) return;
 backgroundUrl = backgroundUrl[1];

 this.resolution = options.resolution || 256;
 this.textureDelta = new Float32Array([1 / this.resolution, 1 / this.resolution]);

 this.perturbance = options.perturbance;

 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 canvas.width = this.$el.outerWidth();
 canvas.height = this.$el.outerHeight();
 this.canvas = canvas;

 this.$el.append(canvas);
 this.context = gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

 // Load extensions
 gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
 gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear');

 // Init events
 $(window).on('resize', function() {
   if (that.$el.outerWidth() != that.canvas.width || that.$el.outerHeight() != that.canvas.height) {
     canvas.width = that.$el.outerWidth();
     canvas.height = that.$el.outerHeight();
   }
 });
 this.$el.on('mousemove', $.proxy(this.mousemove, this));
 this.$el.on('mousemoverel', $.proxy(this.mousemove, this));
 this.$el.on('mousedown', $.proxy(this.mousedown, this));

 // Init textures

 var image = new Image;
 image.crossOrigin = '';
 image.onload = function() {
   gl = that.context;

   function isPowerOfTwo(x) {
     return (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
   }

   var wrapping = (isPowerOfTwo(image.width) && isPowerOfTwo(image.height)) ? gl.REPEAT : gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE;

   that.backgroundWidth = image.width;
   that.backgroundHeight = image.height;

   var texture = gl.createTexture();

   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, 1);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrapping);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrapping);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

   that.backgroundTexture = texture;
 };
 image.src = backgroundUrl;

 this.textures = [];
 this.framebuffers = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   var texture = gl.createTexture();
   var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
   framebuffer.width = this.resolution;
   framebuffer.height = this.resolution;

   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, this.resolution, this.resolution, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);

   var renderbuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
   gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);
   gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, this.resolution, this.resolution);

   gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
   gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);
   if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
     throw new Error('Rendering to this texture is not supported (incomplete framebuffer)');
   }

   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
   gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

   this.textures.push(texture);
   this.framebuffers.push(framebuffer);
 }

 // Init GL stuff
 this.quad = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.quad);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
   -1, -1,
   +1, -1,
   +1, +1,
   -1, +1
 ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 this.initShaders();

 // Init animation
 function step() {
   that.update();
   requestAnimationFrame(step);
 }

 requestAnimationFrame(step);
   };

   Ripples.DEFAULTS = {
 resolution: 456,
 perturbance: 0.01
   };

   Ripples.prototype = {
 update: function() {
   gl = this.context;

   if (!this.backgroundTexture) return;

   this.updateTextures();
   this.render();
 },

 drawQuad: function() {
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.quad);
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
   gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
 },

 render: function() {
   gl.viewport(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
   gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   gl.useProgram(this.renderProgram.id);

   bindTexture(this.backgroundTexture, 0);
   bindTexture(this.textures[0], 1);

   gl.uniform2fv(this.renderProgram.locations.topLeft, this.renderProgram.uniforms.topLeft);
   gl.uniform2fv(this.renderProgram.locations.bottomRight, this.renderProgram.uniforms.bottomRight);
   gl.uniform2fv(this.renderProgram.locations.containerRatio, this.renderProgram.uniforms.containerRatio);
   gl.uniform1i(this.renderProgram.locations.samplerBackground, 0);
   gl.uniform1i(this.renderProgram.locations.samplerRipples, 1);

   this.drawQuad();
 },

 updateTextures: function() {
   this.computeTextureBoundaries();

   gl.viewport(0, 0, this.resolution, this.resolution);

   for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.framebuffers[i]);
     bindTexture(this.textures[1 - i]);
     gl.useProgram(this.updateProgram[i].id);

     this.drawQuad();
   }

   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
 },

 computeTextureBoundaries: function() {
   var backgroundSize = this.$el.css('background-size');
   var backgroundAttachment = this.$el.css('background-attachment');
   var backgroundPosition = this.$el.css('background-position').split(' ');

   // Here the 'window' is the element which the background adapts to 
   // (either the chrome window or some element, depending on attachment)
   var parElement = backgroundAttachment == 'fixed' ? $window : this.$el;
   var winOffset = parElement.offset() || {
     left: pageXOffset,
     top: pageYOffset
   };
   var winWidth = parElement.outerWidth();
   var winHeight = parElement.outerHeight();

   // TODO: background-clip
   if (backgroundSize == 'cover') {
     var scale = Math.max(winWidth / this.backgroundWidth, winHeight / this.backgroundHeight);

     var backgroundWidth = this.backgroundWidth * scale;
     var backgroundHeight = this.backgroundHeight * scale;
   } else if (backgroundSize == 'contain') {
     var scale = Math.min(winWidth / this.backgroundWidth, winHeight / this.backgroundHeight);

     var backgroundWidth = this.backgroundWidth * scale;
     var backgroundHeight = this.backgroundHeight * scale;
   } else {
     backgroundSize = backgroundSize.split(' ');
     var backgroundWidth = backgroundSize[0];
     var backgroundHeight = backgroundSize[1] || backgroundSize[0];

     if (backgroundWidth.endsWith('%')) backgroundWidth = winWidth * parseFloat(backgroundWidth) / 100;
     else if (backgroundWidth == 'auto') backgroundWidth = this.backgroundWidth;
     else backgroundWidth = parseFloat(backgroundWidth);

     if (backgroundHeight.endsWith('%')) backgroundHeight = winHeight * parseFloat(backgroundHeight) / 100;
     else if (backgroundHeight == 'auto') backgroundHeight = this.backgroundHeight;
     else backgroundHeight = parseFloat(backgroundHeight);
   }

   // Compute backgroundX and backgroundY in page coordinates
   var backgroundX = backgroundPosition[0];
   var backgroundY = backgroundPosition[1];

   if (backgroundX == 'left') backgroundX = winOffset.left;
   else if (backgroundX == 'center') backgroundX = winOffset.left + winWidth / 2 - backgroundWidth / 2;
   else if (backgroundX == 'right') backgroundX = winOffset.left + winWidth - backgroundWidth;
   else if (backgroundX.endsWith('%')) {
     backgroundX = winOffset.left + (winWidth - backgroundWidth) * parseFloat(backgroundX) / 100;
   } else {
     backgroundX = parseFloat(backgroundX);
   }

   if (backgroundY == 'top') backgroundY = winOffset.top;
   else if (backgroundY == 'center') backgroundY = winOffset.top + winHeight / 2 - backgroundHeight / 2;
   else if (backgroundY == 'bottom') backgroundY = winOffset.top + winHeight - backgroundHeight;
   else if (backgroundY.endsWith('%')) {
     backgroundY = winOffset.top + (winHeight - backgroundHeight) * parseFloat(backgroundY) / 100;
   } else {
     backgroundY = parseFloat(backgroundY);
   }

   var elementOffset = this.$el.offset();

   this.renderProgram.uniforms.topLeft = new Float32Array([
     (elementOffset.left - backgroundX) / backgroundWidth,
     (elementOffset.top - backgroundY) / backgroundHeight
   ]);
   this.renderProgram.uniforms.bottomRight = new Float32Array([
     this.renderProgram.uniforms.topLeft[0] + this.$el.outerWidth() / backgroundWidth,
     this.renderProgram.uniforms.topLeft[1] + this.$el.outerHeight() / backgroundHeight
   ]);

   var maxSide = Math.max(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

   this.renderProgram.uniforms.containerRatio = new Float32Array([
     this.canvas.width / maxSide,
     this.canvas.height / maxSide
   ]);
 },

 initShaders: function() {
   var vertexShader = [
     'attribute vec2 vertex;',
     'varying vec2 coord;',
     'void main() {',
     'coord = vertex * 0.5 + 0.5;',
     'gl_Position = vec4(vertex, 0.0, 1.0);',
     '}'
   ].join('\n');

   this.dropProgram = createProgram(vertexShader, [
     'precision highp float;',

     'const float PI = 3.141592653589793;',
     'uniform sampler2D texture;',
     'uniform vec2 center;',
     'uniform float radius;',
     'uniform float strength;',

     'varying vec2 coord;',

     'void main() {',
     'vec4 info = texture2D(texture, coord);',

     'float drop = max(0.0, 1.0 - length(center * 0.5 + 0.5 - coord) / radius);',
     'drop = 0.5 - cos(drop * PI) * 0.5;',

     'info.r += drop * strength;',

     'gl_FragColor = info;',
     '}'
   ].join('\n'));

   this.updateProgram = [0, 0];
   this.updateProgram[0] = createProgram(vertexShader, [
     'precision highp float;',

     'uniform sampler2D texture;',
     'uniform vec2 delta;',

     'varying vec2 coord;',

     'void main() {',
     'vec4 info = texture2D(texture, coord);',

     'vec2 dx = vec2(delta.x, 0.0);',
     'vec2 dy = vec2(0.0, delta.y);',

     'float average = (',
     'texture2D(texture, coord - dx).r +',
     'texture2D(texture, coord - dy).r +',
     'texture2D(texture, coord + dx).r +',
     'texture2D(texture, coord + dy).r',
     ') * 0.25;',

     'info.g += (average - info.r) * 2.0;',
     'info.g *= 0.995;',
     'info.r += info.g;',

     'gl_FragColor = info;',
     '}'
   ].join('\n'));
   gl.uniform2fv(this.updateProgram[0].locations.delta, this.textureDelta);

   this.updateProgram[1] = createProgram(vertexShader, [
     'precision highp float;',

     'uniform sampler2D texture;',
     'uniform vec2 delta;',

     'varying vec2 coord;',

     'void main() {',
     'vec4 info = texture2D(texture, coord);',

     'vec3 dx = vec3(delta.x, texture2D(texture, vec2(coord.x + delta.x, coord.y)).r - info.r, 0.0);',
     'vec3 dy = vec3(0.0, texture2D(texture, vec2(coord.x, coord.y + delta.y)).r - info.r, delta.y);',
     'info.ba = normalize(cross(dy, dx)).xz;',

     'gl_FragColor = info;',
     '}'
   ].join('\n'));
   gl.uniform2fv(this.updateProgram[1].locations.delta, this.textureDelta);

   this.renderProgram = createProgram([
     'precision highp float;',

     'attribute vec2 vertex;',
     'uniform vec2 topLeft;',
     'uniform vec2 bottomRight;',
     'uniform vec2 containerRatio;',
     'varying vec2 ripplesCoord;',
     'varying vec2 backgroundCoord;',
     'void main() {',
     'backgroundCoord = mix(topLeft, bottomRight, vertex * 0.5 + 0.5);',
     'backgroundCoord.y = 1.0 - backgroundCoord.y;',
     'ripplesCoord = vec2(vertex.x, -vertex.y) * containerRatio * 0.5 + 0.5;',
     'gl_Position = vec4(vertex.x, -vertex.y, 0.0, 1.0);',
     '}'
   ].join('\n'), [
     'precision highp float;',

     'uniform sampler2D samplerBackground;',
     'uniform sampler2D samplerRipples;',
     'uniform float perturbance;',
     'varying vec2 ripplesCoord;',
     'varying vec2 backgroundCoord;',

     'void main() {',
     'vec2 offset = -texture2D(samplerRipples, ripplesCoord).ba;',
     'float specular = pow(max(0.0, dot(offset, normalize(vec2(-0.6, 1.0)))), 4.0);',
     'gl_FragColor = texture2D(samplerBackground, backgroundCoord + offset * perturbance) + specular;',
     '}'
   ].join('\n'));
   gl.uniform1f(this.renderProgram.locations.perturbance, this.perturbance);
 },

 dropAtMouse: function(e, radius, strength) {
   var that = this;

   gl = this.context;

   e.offsetX = e.offsetX || (e.pageX - this.$el.offset().left);
   e.offsetY = e.offsetY || (e.pageY - this.$el.offset().top);

   var elWidth = this.$el.outerWidth();
   var elHeight = this.$el.outerHeight();
   var longestSide = Math.max(elWidth, elHeight);

   var dropPosition = new Float32Array([
     (2 * e.offsetX - elWidth) / longestSide,
     (elHeight - 2 * e.offsetY) / longestSide
   ]);

   gl.viewport(0, 0, this.resolution, this.resolution);

   // Render onto texture/framebuffer 0
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.framebuffers[0]);

   // Using texture 1
   bindTexture(this.textures[1]);

   gl.useProgram(this.dropProgram.id);
   gl.uniform2fv(this.dropProgram.locations.center, dropPosition);
   gl.uniform1f(this.dropProgram.locations.radius, radius);
   gl.uniform1f(this.dropProgram.locations.strength, strength);

   this.drawQuad();

   // Switch textures
   var t = this.framebuffers[0];
   this.framebuffers[0] = this.framebuffers[1];
   this.framebuffers[1] = t;
   t = this.textures[0];
   this.textures[0] = this.textures[1];
   this.textures[1] = t;

   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
 },

 mousemove: function(e) {
   this.dropAtMouse(e, 0.03, 0.01);
 },

 mousedown: function(e) {
   this.dropAtMouse(e, 0.09, 0.14);
 },
   };

   // RIPPLES PLUGIN DEFINITION
   // ==========================

   var old = $.fn.ripples;

   $.fn.ripples = function(option) {
 return this.each(function() {
   if (!supportsWebGL) throw new Error('Your browser does not support at least one of the following: WebGL, OES_texture_float extension, OES_texture_float_linear extension.');

   var $this = $(this);
   var data = $this.data('ripples');
   var options = $.extend({}, Ripples.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option);

   if (!data)
     $this.data('ripples', new Ripples(this, options));
 });
   }

   $.fn.ripples.Constructor = Ripples;


   // RIPPLES NO CONFLICT
   // ====================

   $.fn.ripples.noConflict = function() {
 $.fn.ripples = old;
 return this;
   }

 }(window.jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

#effect-canvas {
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(https://codertroop.agency/wp-content/themes/agency/main-bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="error"></div>
<div id="effect-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле по тексту ошибки. И внимательно на код посмотреть. Не удивительно, что такой вопрос минусят.

Comment: Открой отладчик f12 или ctrl+shift+j  глянь в консоль, там твоя ошибка. На против текста ошибки, указан номер строки `js:45` щелкни по нему и попадешь на участок кода с меткой, на строке с ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Самая первая функция, вам не кажется, что там нет имени? И в тексте ошибки кроется ответ. Задайте имя функции!